# Can't change adapter in Fragment after Activity being destroyed

Tags: android

I want to change fragment's adapter when user change filter options (Semester in this case).

This is my activity:

[image: My activity]
.

The following code at first moment works fine:

My **Activity** handles the semester change

```
protected void onChangeSemester(String oldSemester, String newSemester) {
    super.onChangeSemester(oldSemester, newSemester);
    if (!oldSemester.equals(newSemester)) {
        pagerAdapter.setSemester(newSemester);
    }
}
```

Then my **pagerAdapter**...

```
public void setSemester(String newSemester) {
    gradesFragment.changeSemester(newSemester, context);
}
```

And finally, my **fragment**:

```
public void changeSemester(String newSemester, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.semester = newSemester;

    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = createAdapter(newSemester);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    adapter.setList(createList(newSemester));
}
```

**BUT...**
After activity being destroyed, code stop working.
[image: App dead]

Then my adapter is recreated in changeSemester, but data doesn't update.
I already tried to **getListView** like that:

```
public void changeSemester(String newSemester, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.semester = newSemester;

    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = (GradeListAdapter) getListView().getAdapter();
    }

    adapter.setList(createList(newSemester));
}
```

But it throws:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created 
    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
    at si.unisanta.tcc.unisantaapp.application.fragments.grade.GradesFragment.changeSemester(GradesFragment.java:110)
    at si.unisanta.tcc.unisantaapp.application.MainActivityPagerAdapter.setSemester(MainActivityPagerAdapter.java:40)
    at si.unisanta.tcc.unisantaapp.application.MainActivity.onChangeSemester(MainActivity.java:210)
    at si.unisanta.tcc.unisantaapp.application.AppCompatActivityToolbarBase$1$1.onClick(AppCompatActivityToolbarBase.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:940)
```

What I'm doing wrong? It looks like that ListView reference is lost and becomes null, **onCreateView** is no called again in my Fragment, so what should be done? There is a way to fix it by recreating fragment, or something else?

Comment: please can you elaborate "After activity being destroyed, code stop working"?

Comment: @Pooya I open my app by first time, it works well. Then I close it by clicking home button. I open any other app and after some time, I reopen my app and it gets buggy like I wrote above. The adapter is destroyed and I can't get the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by not mantaining an instance in adapter.

My FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
//More fields...
private Map<Integer, Fragment> pageReferenceMap = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return ClassesFragment.newInstance();

        case 1:
            return TestsFragment.newInstance();

        case 2:
            return GradesFragment.newInstance(semester);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment)super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    pageReferenceMap.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    pageReferenceMap.remove(position);
}

public void setSemester(String newSemester) {
    this.semester = newSemester;
    Fragment gradesFragment = pageReferenceMap.get(GRADES_INDEX);
    if (gradesFragment != null) {
        ((GradesFragment)gradesFragment).changeSemester(newSemester);
    }
}
```

And that did the trick